# I can connect 2 or more devices for bluetooth and send information?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I can connect 2 or more devices for bluetooth and send information.

Comment: Your question is short and not enough clear. Add more details, use clear sentences, explain what you want. Bluetooth allows at most 7 devices, but I don't know android also supports it.

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/69d7810f6ef9bb7d

I'm not sure that this is what you want.

But in order to connect more than 2 devices using bluetooth you have to create a different UUID for each device you want to connect.

Follow the link to see code examples and a better explanation.